# SwiftUI class init mistake

Tags: class, variables, swiftui, declaration, init

I'm a new beginner in swiftUI and I'm trying to deal with a Class that use CoreLocation to do some places locations comparison. But I've add my structured array of place in my Class and I've got an error with the `override init()`.

My class :

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @ObservedObject var placeLibrary: PlaceLibrary
    
    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus?
    @Published var lastLocation: CLLocation?
    @Published var distanceFromNearest: Double = 0.0
    @Published var nearestObject:String = ""
    
    override init() {
        placeLibrary.testPlace = placeLibrary.testPlace
        super.init() // HERE I GET MY ERROR 
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.placeLibrary = placeLibrary
    }
    
    var statusString: String {
        guard let status = locationStatus else {
            return "unknown"
        }
        
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined: return "notDetermined"
        case .authorizedWhenInUse: return "authorizedWhenInUse"
        case .authorizedAlways: return "authorizedAlways"
        case .restricted: return "restricted"
        case .denied: return "denied"
        default: return "unknown"
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        locationStatus = status
        print(#function, statusString)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        lastLocation = location
        
        for (idx, readOnlyPlace) in placeLibrary.testPlace.enumerated() {
            // Calculate stuff
            let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: (self.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude) ?? 0.0, longitude: (self.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude) ?? 0.0)
            let comparedLocation = CLLocation(latitude: readOnlyPlace.lat, longitude: readOnlyPlace.long)

            // Update struct
            placeLibrary.testPlace[idx].proximity = currentLocation.distance(from: comparedLocation)
        }
        
        placeLibrary.testPlace = placeLibrary.testPlace.sorted(by: { $0.proximity < $1.proximity })
        
        print(placeLibrary.testPlace)
    }
}
```

The error result here is : `Property 'self.placeLibrary' not initialized at super.init call`

After looking on internet I understand that I need to define all my variable used by my Class into the Init. That's why I add this line without any success : `self.placeLibrary = placeLibrary` even if there is before or after the `super.init()` line...

So I think there something I don't understand ...

My Place library :

```
class PlaceLibrary: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var testPlace = [
        Place(lat: 46.1810, long: 6.2304, Name: "Place 1", proximity: 0.0),
        Place(lat: 46.1531, long: 6.2951, Name: "Place 2", proximity: 0.0),
        Place(lat: 46.1207, long: 6.3302, Name: "Place 3", proximity: 0.0)
    ]
}
```

My Place structure :

```
struct Place: Identifiable{
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double
    var Name: String
    var proximity: Double
    
    init (lat: Double, long: Double, Name: String, proximity: Double){
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.Name = Name
        self.proximity = proximity
    }
    
    init(config: NewPlaceConfig){
        self.lat = config.lat
        self.long = config.long
        self.Name = config.Name
        self.proximity = config.proximity
    }
}
```

And finally my NewPlaceConfig

```
struct NewPlaceConfig{
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double
    var Name: String
    var proximity: Double
}
```

Comment: You are trying to access `placeLibrary.testPlace` before initialising `placeLibrary`. Instead of `@ObservedObject var placeLibrary: PlaceLibrary` you can use `@StateObject var placeLibrary = PlaceLibrary()`. Then you can also remove `placeLibrary.testPlace = placeLibrary.testPlace` which makes no sense because you are reassigning the exact same thing to itself.

Comment: An `@ObservedObject` property wrapper makes no sense in a class conforming to `ObservableObject`. It's only useful in a SwiftUI **View**. Apart from that it's still more pointless as the `@Published` object is actually a constant.

Comment: That give me the same error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `placeLibrary` property is, like the error messages says, not initialized.

`ObservedObject`, in this instance, does nothing. The `@ObservedObject` property wrapper should only be used in `View` structs. It tells the `View` to observe the object for any changes, so that Swift knows when to redraw or recalculate the view. Other than that, it does nothing in regards to initialization.

So, really, the property is declared as `var placeLibrary: PlaceLibrary`. **This declaration does not initialize the property**, it only describes the type that it will hold.

You can either initialize it yourself before the `super.init` call using `self.placeLibrary = PlaceLibrary()`, or, more concisely, initialize it at the property declaration site itself:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var placeLibrary = PlaceLibrary()
    
    // ...

    // Alternatively, initialize the property in the init()
    override init() {
        self.placeLibrary = PlaceLibrary()
        super.init()
        // ...
        // Remaining initialization code
    }
}
```

I would also replace `var` with `let`, but that is your choice.

Comment: Oh ok great I understand now ! I was thinking that if I would like to access to my array anywhere in my code I need to call it via `@ObservedObject` but ok now I understand that some property wrapper is only using in view but not in some other part of my code ! Many many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`Property 'self.placeLibrary' not initialized at super.init call`

The problem is not with your `super.init()` call, but because you are trying to access a property of a class before this class is fully initialized (like the message says).

Edit: This seems odd at first. But you cannot guarantee the order that the compiler will call and initialize your class. You can only have certain that a class is fully initialized after `init()` finishes. That's why you cannot use properties inside the init, by definition, only initialize.

Edit2: Easiest way to fix is make optional. If you have certain that this property will never go back to nil again you can make it automatically upwrapped with `!`.

Edit3: Something like this:

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    private var number: Int!
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    convenience init(test: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.number = test
    }
}

class MyClass {
    var location: LocationManager
    
    init(location: LocationManager) {
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

Note the optional property here `Int!`

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm starting to understand better but understand and applicate is not the same. So if I'd like to use my `@ObservedObject var placeLibrary: PlaceLibrary` I need to initialize it on the `init()` but if I write something like : `placeLibrary.testPlace = [Place(lat: 0, long: 0, Name: "0", proximity: 0)]` is not working too ...

Comment: No. If this was a _totally yours_ class, you could write a custom initializer like `init(testPlaces: MyTestPlaces) -> Void {}`and inside the init, `self.testPlaces = testPlaces`, the problem here is that you are overriding a superclass that don't have this initializer. So you make your property optional then initialize later. Or you initialize **Empty** then attribute your places later. Either way you'll have to adjust your logic to deal with optional state or empty state.

Comment: This is not true. As long as you initialize your own class's properties before the `super.init()` call takes place, you're fine. There is no requirement to make the properties of a subclass optional, it's just that this will work automatically because optionals are automatically assigned a `nil` value if not explicitly initialized.

Comment: That is true **Cheezzhead**, my mistake. I'll promote your answer as a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, no worries. It is true that most of the time making a property optional is the best way to do this. I just wanted to communicate *why* this is not necessarily always the case